# Finding the frequency of CAN (controller area network) send and receive messages

Tags: frequency

How can I find the frequency of CAN send and CAN receive messages using Ubuntu terminal?

I'm sending CAN messages using a serial port and receiving it with a Peak CAN USB.

I can find the bit rate with `ifconfig` but I don't know a command which shows me the frequency or clock rate.

There are no errors and no dropped messages between receiving and sending sides but I don't know the command to get the frequency.
I'm using only simple candump and can send commands in Ubuntu.
I know the bps but I want to know the frequency of sending and receiving sides.

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What is "CAN"? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster i gave explanation. please share some idea to get the frequency as we get the bps by using just ifconfing in CAN area

Comment: I still don’t know what “CAN” is and I wouldn’t know how to search for it because it’s 1) a very common English word which rules out Google searches  and 2) a three-letter acronym with [7 uses in computing known to Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN#Computing). I also don’t know what *exactly* you did so far which may help to understand which feature gaps you’re trying to fill between the things you already know how to do.

Comment: @David Foerster CAN is controller area network and i'm using Peak CAN usb for receiving messages.

Comment: I have no experience in this area, but I think when you say "Peak CAN USB", you mean Peak PCAN-USB, yes? And when you say "can send" command, you mean `cansend` command?

Comment: @siddiqui_902003: That appears to settle one question at least. What *exactly* are you currently doing? Don’t let us pull every detail out of your nose! ;-)